# How to show individual tooltips after loading a chart?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I would like the highchart to behave in this way: 
Immediately after loading the chart, no tooltips is shown. When a button is clicked for the first time, the tooltip of the first data point is shown; when the button is clicked for the second time, the tooltip of the first data point disappears and the tooltip of the second data point is shown, etc.  The tooltip needs to be shown without having a mouse hovering over the data point.
The graph should not be interactive throughout the process.

After clicking the button after the last data point is shown, all tooltips are enabled.

I have tried to use, among others, tooltip.refresh(point) and hide(), without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable mouse tracking for the series and use `tooltip.refresh(point)` and `tooltip.hide`

```
var i = -1;

$('#show-tt').on('click', function() {
   var points = chart.series[0].points;
   chart.tooltip.hide();
   chart.tooltip.refresh(points[++i % points.length]);
});


var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  series: [{
    enableMouseTracking: false,
    data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
  }]
});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/sfty1xd7/

Comment: Thank you! Sorry that I updated the question again. Is it possible enable all tooltips after clicking the button after the last data point is shown with your method?

Comment: Yes, you need to create multiple tooltips and disable the default tooltip after the last click. http://jsfiddle.net/sfty1xd7/1/